# Open Wordpress SQL file to get data

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I had a website from a few years ago. The site is long gone. But I've still got the database.

The site had about 200 posts/articles that I'd like to get back.

I tried to import it into a new wordpress website but it fails for me.. and the site just goes to a white page.. most likely fatal errors.

As i don't need the articles on a wordpress site I don't mind which way I get them. If i was able to get them I would put them back into a wordpress site.

Does anyone know how I can get the articles?

Comment: If you have a .sql file (i.e. a backup, then it should be easy)

Comment: What is the file extension of the backup?  Is it a directory full of things or a single file?

Comment: do you have some knowdeledge about sql manipulation or just plain user trying to play wizardry with wordpress?

Comment: sorry forgot to add I don't know anything about SQL, exported the database from phpmyadmin... then i installed wordpress again and dropped all the tables in the new sql database and then import the old database

Comment: ANy help would be great

Comment: possible duplicate of [get data stored in .sql file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501478/get-data-stored-in-sql-file)